# popup text box on hover without access to html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

Im trying to create a popupbox with text on mouseover. My problem is that I dont have access to the html, and I cant upload javascript- I can however do css and write Javascript.

Most example I find either requires you to change the cssclasses, or upload a Javascript. Since I cant link in internal script, that fails.

Can I do this with Javascript without the need to upload a scriptfile?

hmtl example, where the span class is the one I need to target:

```
<a href="/products/Microsoft/All-in-One-Media-Keyboard-with-TouchPad-German-?prodid=1676284">All-in-One Media Keyboard with TouchPad German  <span class="labelextension N2">Bulk</span> </a>
```

Comment: Can you clarify the way you can use javascript in your case? As in, can you not upload files, but add javascript to the HTML in a `<script>` tag?

Comment: Hi! The website im trying to do this is a closed business platform, where i cant access  the basic html. It does have input windows for javascript and css, but there is no upload options, i cant place a javascript somewhere, but I can write it and paste it on the javascript input window.

Comment: Assuming they include the javascript you enter into that box in a convenient place in the HTML document, you could access the elements you want to have the hover popup with `document.getElement(s)ById/TagName/etc` and then modify the dom to suit your needs. Can you post an HTML code sample of the element(s) you want to have the hover effect?

Answer (score 0):

This is a VERY crude example on how to do what you described:

- get the triggering element (`$('.labelextension')`)
- create an element that is going to be the popup (`popup = document.createElement(...)`)
- attach the element to the triggering element (`...appendChild(popup)`)
- change its css so that it is only displayed when the mouse hovers the triggering element (`popup.classList.add('tooltip')` and `.tooltip {display:none} .labelextension:hover .tooltip {display : inline;}`)

A rather crummy JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kcdagqdn/

Comment: Hi and thanks! Not having much of luck with the fiddle though. Nothing happend until i changed the class to span.labelextension, it then removed all labels inasted?

Comment: Leave the classes as they are and mouse over the "Bulk" text. A box should appear next to it.